# SQL - count the number of new users each year

Tags: sql

I have a transaction table which has a visit_date for every transaction like below

```
customer_id     visit_date
1                  2018
2.                 2019
1                  2020
4                  2020
5                  2020
```

I want to calculate the total number of new users added in each year. i.e. In the above example in year 2018 - there was only 1 customer( id 1), and in 2019, one new customer added(id 2) and similarly in year 2020, there were two new customers( 4 and 5).

I can calculate the number of users in each year with a simple group by count(distinct(customer_id)). But here i want to calculate, for e.g. how many new users came in year 2020 who were not there in 2019. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select min_visit_date, count(*) as num_new_customers
from (select customer_id, min(visit_date) as min_visit_date
      from t
      group by customer_id
     ) t
group by min_visit_date;
```